# Pruning small tomato plant?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, tomatoes, outdoor, tomatillos

I bought this tomato plant some time ago, and it grew about 3 small tomatoes.

The tomato plant currently looks like this. I’m not sure if it’s dying, but the tomatoes grew in the dying branches.

Now it’s growing new branches, but I’m not sure how to (or if I need to) prune it.

The plant currently has two branches: one new branch is growing in one old branch, and the second branch is growing just below the “V” (the main branch).

NOTE: The green you see in the 2nd and 3rd pic is from another plant.

What do you recommend? Here are some pics:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you cut back to depends on whether your tomato plant is grafted onto another rootstock - it may be that the growth at the base is off the rootstock if its grafted, and that won't be the same variety of tomato as the topgrowth. If it is not grafted, I suggest you cut it right back to just above the green growth towards the base of the plant and let it grow on anew, assuming you live in a part of the world that doesn't really get winter or you're in the southern hemisphere. If it is grafted, cut off the dead wood on the right, and cut back to the upper growth bud on the other stem and remove the growth at the base, unless you're up for an experiment and want to see what the plant produces if the basal growth is left to grow on.

Comment: Thanks. I don’t think it’s grafted.

Comment: Is it common for the branch that had the tomatoes to die?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid - where I live, tomatoes are simply an annual crop and would by now be on the compost heap because of winter. Maybe too much heat did it, but either way, the soil in the pot is rather low, it could be an inch or so higher and if you did not feed regularly when it was starting to fruit, that might account for it too. Certainly would accouint for only three fruits...